# Vue.js and Laravel type casting

Tags: javascript, laravel, vue.js, vuejs2

I'm using DB2-style IDs for my database records in my laravel 5.7 app-- for example, `201402241121000000000000`. In my vue component I'm calling it like this:

```
<mycomponent v-bind:listing-key="{{ $listing->listing_key }}"></mycomponent>
```

In the component js, it shows the prop as

```
export default {
    props: {
        'listingKey': String,
    },
```

However, this throws the error

```
[Vue warn]: Invalid prop: type check failed for prop "listingKey". Expected String with value "2.01402241121e+23", got Number with value 2.01402241121e+23.
```

Is the `v-bind` trying to bind a number instead of treating it as a string?

Comment: Have you tried [type casting](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.type-juggling.php#language.types.typecasting) `$listing->listing_key`?

Comment: Can you try wrapping the value in single quotes?May be something like this  v-bind:listing-key=" ''+{{ $listing->listing_key }}".So that it will convert your value to string rather than number.

Answer (score 1):

@Riddhi had suggested very much the answer. The solution was to do this:

```
< mycomponent v-bind:listing-key="'{{ $listing->listing_key }}'"></mycomponent >
```

Thanks @Riddhi!